# Notifications for my site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/2PeEK/19/

I set `numOfNewNotifications` to be the number of `li` that their `hasRead` attribute is false.

Meantime, I put `numOfNewNotifications` in the middle of the globes.

how can I do it like the notification of facebook please?

[image]

I want to put it only if the numOfNewNotifications is not zero

any help appreciated!

Comment: If you just want to edit the number's position in the image, you should consider using CSS. So I would suggest adding CSS as a tag as well...

Comment: I want to put it only if the numOfNewNotifications is not zero. I will try to do what you suggested, thank you!

Comment: Then you should have added that detail to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest css for Facebook style "red" notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747863/easiest-css-for-facebook-style-red-notifications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image is [image], consider an image without whiteblock like [image]and have whiteblock `div` externally.  So that we can easily position it using `css`.

Please have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5748155/1671639) and their [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techappetite/b8K77/1/).

I have done something [image] similar to yours, check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PeEK/20/)

Added **HTML**:

```
<div id="whit"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#whit {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

change your **JS**:

```
$("#whit").text(numOfNewNotifications);
```

Comment: thank you very much! I used what you suggested me.. thank you very much!

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/2PeEK/26/

Comment: @AlonShmiel I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: @AlonShmiel looks nice.  One suggestion, never have numerials as `id` always start with alphabets.