# facebook style notification in html button using only hml and css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a button that has some notification attached to it and am trying to emulate the facebook notification styles. A little red circle in the top right corner with a number in it.

I'm having some issues with it though. I can't seem to get the circle in the right place or to get the number to actually sit inside of it.

my button looks like this

```
<button class="btn btn-blue" id="noteBtn">Notes <span class="notification">1</span></button>
```

and I've tred to do this with my css

```
.notification:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 5em;
  color:red;
}
```

here is a js fiddle I was working with

http://jsfiddle.net/N8cjB/5/

Comment: put number in other span that is sibling of this `<span class="notification">` and then set the new span (in which number show) using margins

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you're saying... put a span within my span to put the number in? That has no effect other then to add more space between the circle and the number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest CSS for "red circle" notification badge with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747863/easiest-css-for-red-circle-notification-badge-with-count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` and I don't get along, so I changed it to a `<div>`

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/aXvqW/3/

**edit** moved it out of the button a little bit, as requested.

Comment: There's no way to take it out of the button to sit on the top right corner?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that was what you were going for! [how's this - jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aXvqW/3/)

Answer (score -1):

To make it simple you don't need **`:before`**.

Add **`border-radius`** to the span, and to center the number use **`text-align: center`**

```
.notification {
      border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: red;
    width:20px;
    height:10px;
    background: red;
    padding: 2px;

}
```

Check this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8cjB/13/)

Comment: Thats not really what I was going for though, I was really going to the top right corner circle with the number in it

Comment: this is poorly positioned, sitting right on/inside the button, rather than offset and on top so that it stands out and apart, as is now standard practice since it gives the best UX.

Answer (score -1):

Change `<span>` to `<div>` and make button `position:relative;` and notification `position:absolute;` using CSS then put it wherever you want.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/N8cjB/26/

**Code**

```css
.button{
  margin:20px 0px;
  border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background:#f9f9f9;
  padding:5px 10px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}

button:hover{
  background:#333;
  border:1px solid #333;
  color:#fff;
}
.notifications {
      position:absolute;
      border-radius:2px;
      font-size:14px;
      background-color:red;
      color:#fff;
      padding:2px 5px;
      top:-10px;
      right:-10px;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button">
Notes<div class="notifications">1</div>
</button>
```

Comment: they wanted a circle, as is common these days.