# How can I make the checkmark symbol added on the button to scroll with it together?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a checkmark symbol on the button to indicate that the page visited, but I don't know how to make it scroll with the button? The only way I succeeded in putting the symbol on is by looking at the answers here to add the checkmark symbol like adding a notification sign using absolute position. ([Easiest css for Facebook style "red" notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747863/easiest-css-for-facebook-style-red-notifications))

But the absolute position makes the checkmark not scrollable, so how can I add the symbol to it and makes it scrollable with the buttons? The effects I wanna achieve is attached here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqoDG.png)

```
body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
iframe{
    height: calc(100% - 90px);
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ribbon{
    height:125px;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background:#F4F4F4;
    z-index:1000;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
}

.ribbon-buttons{
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.ribbon-button {
    overflow: auto;
    height:65px;
    line-height:44px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#D6D6D6;
    width:65px;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin-right:26px;
    margin-left:9px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}


.logo{
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:5px;
}



.active {
    background-color:#50E3C2;
    opacity: 1; 
}

.checkmark{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-image: url('checkmark.png');
    position:absolute;
    left: 65;
    top: 50;
    display:inline-block;
}

    <body>
<div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-buttons">
            <div class="ribbon-button active">
                <div class="logo" ></div><div class="checkmark"></div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance! I am really new to html/css, so not really sure how to achieve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/lajlev/pen/diKbz you can make it large as your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button must have position:relative

Comment: Welcome to the site! As you're new here, I'll give you a tip.The point of Stack Overflow is to help others learn, rather than just providing them with some code. We are not a free code-writing service, after all. Just providing the answer without an explanation is therefore not considered a good answer. Please read [How do I write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on the philosophy and expectations of Stack Overflow and its community.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` positions the element within the closest positioned element that it is inside. Because you didn't position your button, the checkmark is now positioned inside the document.

If you add `position:relative` to the button's css, like below, the checkmark will be positioned inside the button, which will make it move wherever the button moves.

```
.ribbon-button {
    overflow: auto;
    height:65px;
    line-height:44px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#D6D6D6;
    width:65px;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin-right:26px;
    margin-left:9px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position:relative;
}
```